# Replacing Every date before a Certain Day with that Day SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite, date

```
SELECT 
    "Trade Details 2".Portfolio, 
    "Trade Details 2".CONTRACT_ID, 
    "Trade Details 2".START_DATE, 
    "Trade Details 2".MATURITY_DATE, 
    "Trade Details 2".NOTIONAL1, 
    "Trade Details 2".CONTRACT_NPV, 
    "Trade Details".TERM
FROM
    "Trade Details 2" 
JOIN 
    "Trade Details" 
WHERE 
    "Trade Details 2".CONTRACT_ID = "Trade Details".FCC_ID 
    AND ("Trade Details 2".NOTIONAL1 > "0.0") 
    AND ("Trade Details 2".MATURITY_DATE > "20180621")
ORDER BY 
    CONTRACT_ID asc
```

I've been able to make sure that every Maturity_Date is after June 21st, 2018, but I'm having trouble with the START_DATE. My goal is to have every date before June 22nd, 2018 be replaced by June 22nd, 2018, in the START_DATE column.

I have tried to replace "Trade Details 2".START_DATE<2018-06-22 WITH 2018-06-22), to no avail. Is there any way to do this in SQL?

Comment: You are looking for a CASE statement. Rather than If True Then DoSomething Else DoSomethingDifferent End If in SQL you do CASE WHEN condition = True THEN DoSomething ELSE DoSomethingDifferent END

Answer (score 1):

You can write the query like this, assuming SQLite:

```
SELECT td2.Portfolio, td2.CONTRACT_ID, 
       MAX(td2.START_DATE, '2018-06-22') as START_DATE
       td2.MATURITY_DATE, td2.NOTIONAL1, td2.CONTRACT_NPV, 
       td.TERM
FROM "Trade Details 2" td2 JOIN 
     "Trade Details" td
     ON td2.CONTRACT_ID = td.FCC_ID AND
        td2.NOTIONAL1 > 0.0 AND
        td2.MATURITY_DATE > '20180621'
ORDER BY  CONTRACT_ID asc;
```

Notes:

- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- Presumably, `NOTIONAL1` is a number, so compare to a number, not a string.
- `JOIN` is good syntax.  There should always be an `ON` clause.
- In SQLite, `MIN()` and `MAX()` take multiple arguments.  With multiple arguments they are not aggregation functions, instead behaving like `LEAST()` and `GREATEST()` in other databases.

Answer (score 0):

See start_date_bounded. Since you didn't tag your dbms the syntax might need tweaked (ex. DATE '2018-06-22'.

```
SELECT "Trade Details 2".Portfolio, "Trade Details 2".CONTRACT_ID, 
CASE WHEN "Trade Details 2".START_DATE < 2018-06-22 THEN 2018-06-22
     ELSE "Trade Details 2".START_DATE
 END AS start_date_bounded, "Trade Details 2".MATURITY_DATE, "Trade Details 
2".NOTIONAL1, "Trade Details 2".CONTRACT_NPV, "Trade Details".TERM
FROM "Trade Details 2" 
JOIN "Trade Details" 
WHERE "Trade Details 2".CONTRACT_ID="Trade Details".FCC_ID and
("Trade Details 2".NOTIONAL1 > "0.0") and
("Trade Details 2".MATURITY_DATE > "20180621")

ORDER BY CONTRACT_ID asc
```

Comment: Tried that and there were no errors, but none of the start dates actually changed. Could it have something to do with the fact that the Start dates are all date and time, so I would need to do `CASE WHEN "Trade Details 2".START_DATE < 2018-06-22 00:00:00 THEN 2018-06-22
     ELSE "Trade Details 2".START_DATE` because when I try that I get an error "near 00"

Comment: Could you post the DDL and sample data? Is start date stored as a string or a date?

Comment: This is in DB Browser for SQLite and it appears to be in a string. It's written as DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS